Is it essential to use the correct word among the synonymous words?
I'm not a native English speaker, I've seen that there are many words in English that have different synonyms. Some of them are,
(sneak out, creep out), (stare, gaze), (exhaustion, fatigue), (essential, crucial, very important)
And so on. I think these words can be used interchangeably in many situations, but there are some details for each word that make one word more appropriate to describe the specific situation.
I'm wondering, if native English speakers use the correct synonym in different situations that is consistent with the details. For example, as a non-native speaker, if I don't know the details of each meaning and use an inappropriate synonym, will a native speaker notice and so it's important to understanding the details and choose the right word?

You need to provide clear examples  but, for example, to sneak out is not to creep out, Also, each of those other terms have different semantic features that make them different from each other. Yes, if you use the wrong word in a particular context a native speaker will notice it. For example, again, exhaustion is more tired than fatigue. Fatigue and tiredness are synonyms. Sometimes, essential and crucial can be used in the same way. Not always.

@Lambie Thanks! Actually, before writing these groups of words, I checked if they are synonyms in famous dictionaries. It is strange to me that some of them are not close in meaning.

Just because a dictionary says they are synonyms does not mean they are exactly the same. There are nuances.

Some synonyms are more (or less) polite, educated, formal, etc. So people who only know of synonyms may say 'knackered' in a situation where 'tired' might be more appropriate.

I very much doubt that there is any difference in any other language.  Is it really the case that you only have a single word for "tiredness"?  A single word for "looking"? That there are no synonyms in your language.  English is no different!

@JamesK Yes, that's exactly right! I'm Persian and there are many synonyms for many words, including your example. We use them without thinking, but it gets confusing and hard to remember the differences of synonyms in other languages :)

The "connotation" of a word is the emotional associations it has. That's generally more important for word choice than the dictionary definition. The connotation of "stare" is generally anger, confusion, or surprise. The connotation of "gaze" is generally admiration and happiness. In most cases, the connotation matters a lot more than the details of the definition.. In other cases, like essential/crucial/very important, the connotations are similar so it doesn't particularly matter.

Sometimes.  Its hard to be more specific than that.
This is not a special feature of English, so you should think about your own language. Google translate gives four or five Persian translations of "stare".  These probably cover several senses of stare, from the long look that two lovers might give each other, to the careful look that a detective gives some evidence, to a cat looking at mousehole, to voyeur looking through a keyhole.
There are lots of connotations.  In some situations "stare" and "gaze" could be replaced by each other: "The man stared/gazed at the sea".  In others it would be wrong.  "The lovers gazed into each other's eyes".  "Don't stare at that person, it's rude".  "He is a stargazer, a birdwatcher, and tv viewer"
Part of learning a language is learning the connotations and the colocations.  Nobody said this is easy, but it is possible - after all, you manage it in your native language!
